# Using jQuery to select div with class signed by ruby iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a click event where a user clicks a link that toggles a dropdown window. But only one window at a time.

```js
$(".one").on('click', function(){
    $(".two").slideToggle();
  });
```

```html
<div class="row visual_wrap text-center">
  <ul class="containerviz no-bullet text-center">
    <% @visualizations.each do |visualization| %>
    <li class="viz-list-style">
      <div class="one <%= visualization.id %>" style="background-image: url('<%= visualization.cover_image.to_s %>')" ><%= visualization.title %></div>
      <div class="two <%= visualization.id %>">some text to check</div>      
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since I'm iterating through a database to bring each visualization to the page. I want a user to select a single visualization that will toggle a dropdown for it. But since I'm differentiating the each visualizations div by their class I'm not sure how to write that in jQuery. Right now the above jQuery will open and close every single visualization if I click any of them. How can I make this more specific? I've tried using an on click event with `$(this).find('.two').slidetoggle();`. But that did not work.

Comment: A `div` can't be a direct child of an `ul`, so start by creating valid markup

Comment: So I created valid markup and now the ```div``` is inside the ```li```. My solution still does not work however.

Comment: if you want to include code snippet just create a mock version using only jquery. you can simulate the different class names by doing `<div class="one 1"> <div class="two 1">  <div class="one 2"> <div class="two 2">` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.two').hide()
       $('.one').on('click', (function() {
          $(this).next('.two').slideDown(200);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your edited version and it did not work either. Also it seems the second to last line is missing a )!

Comment: Actually it turned out to be a css issue. Sorry about that. This works! If I wanted to push divs down that are directly below the div sliding down. How would I do that?

Comment: @scotchpasta i am not sure what you mean exactly. div class two is covering up something when it slides down that you don't want it to cover?

Comment: Hey Timmmy, I was able to tweak it using css. This worked great however..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way of identifying the trigger and its target element. There are a few ways you can do this:

- via their relationship in the DOM (for example, you can make both the trigger and the target children of the same element).
- via some attribute on the elements. IDs, data attributes, or other attributes can be used.

The best way, I think, is to use HTML's built in semantics and functionality: Links that target elements in the document by their ID's. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9pc3mk2k/

Try the following HTML (class names adjusted for clarity):

```
<div class="row visual_wrap text-center">
  <ul class="containerviz no-bullet text-center">
    <% @visualizations.each do |visualization| %>
    <li class="viz-list-style">
      <a href="#vis-<%= visualization.id %>" class="vis-trigger" style="background-image: url('<%= visualization.cover_image.to_s %>')" ><%= visualization.title %></a>
      <div id="vis-<%= visualization.id %>" class="vis-target">some text to check</div>      
    </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this JS:

```
$("a.vis-trigger").on('click', function(){
  var target = $($(this).attr('href')).slideToggle();
  return false;
});
```

This approach allows you to move or change the hierarchy of you HTML, as long as your trigger is a link pointing to the ID, the behaviour will continue to work.

Comment: Thanks! the functionality is there. I'm running into an issue however whenever a trigger is clicked, there is a jarring movement and the view is jerked to the top of the page. I tried to change the ```slideToggle(200);``` but haven't had any luck.

Comment: if this is happening in mobile you can try to place: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1">` at the top of your page

Comment: That sounds like the 'return false' isn't preventing the browser's native 'scroll to the element' behaviour for some reason. I'll update the JS code with a different approach. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Actually, @scotchpasta, it was just a typo. Try the updated javascript instead.